# concatenate NSString with loop

Tags: objective-c

I have this code below, which creates a loop and will loop inserting values ​​into a variable:

```
int i;
NSString *idts;

for(i=0;i<11;i++){

idts = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d<-+->",i];

}

NSLog(@"ORDER -> %@",idts);
```

I wonder how could I concatenate the values ​​of the variable "idts" inside the loop, because the console shows me the following message:

> 10<-+->

while, should appear as follows:

> 1<-+->2<-+->3<-+->4<-+->5<-+->6<-+->7<-+->8<-+->9<-+->10

Someone can help me?

Comment: Why -1 votes? with no justifications?

Comment: I did not down vote, but people generally don't tell you why they've down voted because they don't want to deal with the backlash. As to speculation for why you may have been down voted though, you don't seem to have put any effort into debugging your problem before posting -- in fact, posting probably took more effort than you used debugging. I say this because there's really very little to your code and it would not be difficult to realize on your own that you're not concatenating anything -- and had you used the debugger to step through code it could not help but be obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
NSString *idts = @"";

for(int i=0;i<11;i++){

    idts = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d<-+->", idts, i];

}
```

Otherwise, your not adding to the current string, you're overwriting the variable.

#### Update

Based on @anon's comment, here's a way to get the exact output from your question:

```
NSString *idts = @"";

for(int i=0;i<11;i++){

    idts = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d%@", idts, i, (i != 10) ? @"<-+->" : @""];

}
```

And @rmaddy's - A mutable string would be more efficient

```
NSMutableString *idts = [NSMutableString string];

for(int i=0;i<11;i++){

    [idts appendFormat:@"%d%@", i, (i != 10) ? @"<-+->" : @""];

}
```

Comment: Well, one small exception to this answer: He needs to handle the end case of 10... yours prints 1 ... 10<-+-> but it's pretty trivial to do. +1

Comment: @anon - ya, I didn't see that.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Anon is right the final result I don't want a 10<-+->, and yes <-+->10, but this values will go to an array, and I think the final array will save a null value, to this I can delete the final array, so thanks :)

Comment: Did you see my update that will print how you prefer?

Comment: It's far more efficient to use a mutable string.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `NSMutableString` and its `appendString` method.

```
NSMutableString *idts = [NSMutableString string];

for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){

    [idts appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d<-+->",i]];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
idts = [idts stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d<-+->", i];
```